# OpenShift tools show disk quota has NOT been exceeded but file saving fails due to disk space

Tags: openshift

I have the following error in my app logs:

```
==> app-root/logs/postgresql.log <==
2016-06-22 13:05:40 GMT ERROR:  could not extend file "base/16385/123494": Disk quota exceeded
2016-06-22 13:05:40 GMT HINT:  Check free disk space.
```

Running all the Red Hat's suggested commands about disk space usage (including `rhc app-tidy`) show that the gear is still under the maximum limit for the free plan:

```
$ rhc show-app --gears quota
Gear                     Cartridges                           Used Limit
------------------------ ---------------------------------- ------ -----
<CUT>                    python-2.7 postgresql-9.2 cron-1.4 294 MB  1 GB
```

SSH'ing to my gear:

```
[<CUT>]\> du -a -h --max-depth=1 | sort -hr
281M    .
102M    ./app-root
...
```

Checking the suggested inode usage reveals nothing:

```
[<CUT>]\> quota -s
Disk quotas for user <CUT> (uid 2372): 
     Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
/dev/mapper/EBSStore01-user_home01
                   281M       0   1024M           18088       0   80000
```

So all seems to be good and within the limits but still the file save fails.

What other tools can I use in OpenShift to see the *real* disk space usage or how would I solve this?